# When redirecting to HTTPS from www, index.php appears in URL

Tags: htaccess, https

I have a redirect setup for *www*, it successfully redirects to *https://* but it includes **/index.php?p=** in the URL. I'm not convinced by htaccess file is configured correctly.

Here's my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Help much appreciated.

Comment: There are some docs on the Craft site for removing `index.php` from your URL's. If you haven't already, take a look: https://craftcms.com/support/remove-index.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are docs for removing `index.php` from your URLs here: https://craftcms.com/support/remove-index.php

There are also docs for enforcing SSL for all CP requests here: https://craftcms.com/support/force-ssl

Note that they mention the the SSL rewrite should happen *before* the `index.php` rewrite in your `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 1):

Using MediaTemple, I have this working:

```
#FORCE HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]

    # REMOVE INDEX.PHP
    RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```